# switch the order of ln and lim.

Tags: calculus

I'm poor att googling on english math terms (don't read english math) and I wonder **when you can switch the order of ln and lim.** Is it for continous function? Context: It is used in the proof of 1/x * ln(1+x) -> 1 when x -> 0.

Comment: note to self: del B # 1 oxå.

Comment: You can interchange the limit operation and a function whenever the function is continuous at that point (0 in this case). In your case however, it's 1/x that will cause trouble if you try to just substitute x with 0.

Comment: so how do I deal with that in this context?

Answer (score 1):

This is most definitely a duplicate, but anyway: 
you can write your limit as

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \log(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

and then, substituting $x=\frac{1}{t}$

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \log(1+\frac{1}{t})^t$$

and now you can interchange $\lim$ and $\log$.

Comment: I know in what step you can do it. But *why*?

Comment: You could not use it when the expression was in the initial form because that function is not continuous in 0. But $\log(1+x)$ is continuous for $x \to 0$ (as $\log$ is continuous at $1$) and of course $x^t$ is continuous. Is it clearer?